# POST http request C# - Request Payload

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, httprequest

I'm trying to POST HTTP request on C# .NET app, i need some help
because i have no idea if that is possible using the request data from google chrome developer tools.

General :

```
Request URL: https://my.domain.ae/data/verify/Proc
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: ip:443
```

Request Payload :

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryWVKBQMeG4O3GcfXR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Id"

016
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVKBQMeG4O3GcfXR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Lvl"

10
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVKBQMeG4O3GcfXR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Name"

Test
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVKBQMeG4O3GcfXR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Score"

23
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVKBQMeG4O3GcfXR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Coins"

100
------WebKitFormBoundaryWVKBQMeG4O3GcfXR--
```

Request Headers :

```
:authority: my.domain.ae
:method: POST
:path: /data/verify/Proc
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 617
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWVKBQMeG4O3GcfXR
cookie: user_language=ar; ****
origin: https://my.domain.ae
referer: https://my.domain.ae/index
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Are you trying to read the response back from your request?

Comment: i cannot even post it , i want to post it and get the response back

Comment: you can't usually do this easily with `c# asp.net` it uses "Regenerate SID" sessional protection to stop session fixation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation, also, in c# do you have a Controller that matches this pattern of form data?

Comment: no, this data post from the website . it has 4 textboxes and a combo box to update the user info and a button to confirm

Comment: so im trying to do this using a c# .net app

Comment: i can get the new SID everytime before posting as well